# Why is bgcolor stopping HTML table export to Excel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, export-to-excel

I am new to JS. I have been able to successfully export HTML tables using the following JS code. However, whenever I use the background color on any field in the table, either `<td>` or `<tr>`, the contents of the field and all following data fields of the table do not appear in the excel file exported. 
Does the command `bgcolor="#CCD1D1"` interfere with `tableSelect.outerHTML`?

How do I get around exporting an HTML table that has a row (or cell) shaded grey?

below HTML exports all data till row2 col1. If I remove the bgcolor="#CCD1D1", the entire table is properly exported

```html
    <button onclick="exportToExcel('testData', 'test-data')">Export</button>  
      <table id = "testData" class = "table table-hover">
        <thead >
        <tr><th> One Title in Header</th></tr>  
        <tr>
          <th>Header1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
          <th>Header 4**</th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Row1 Col1</td>
            <td>Row1 Col2</td>
            <td>Row1 Col3</td>
            <td>Row1 Col4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Row2 Col1</td>
            <td bgcolor="#CCD1D1">Row2 Col2</td>
            <td>Row2 Col3</td>
            <td>Row2 Col4**</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

The JavaScript used for exporting is as follows (it works fine where no background shading is used in the table):

```js
    function exportToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
        var downloadurl;
        var dataFileType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
        var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var tableHTMLData = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

        // Specify file name
        filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'export_excel_data.xls';

        // Create download link element
        downloadurl = document.createElement("a");

        document.body.appendChild(downloadurl);

        if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
            var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTMLData], {
                type: dataFileType
            });
            navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
        }else{
            // Create a link to the file
            downloadurl.href = 'data:' + dataFileType + ', ' + tableHTMLData;

            // Setting the file name
            downloadurl.download = filename;

            //triggering the function
            downloadurl.click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am going to guess that because `#` has a special meaning in an URL so that when you add it as part of the `download.href` it truncates the content until that point.  You are likely going to need to add a class to assign colour to the bg via CSS

Comment: `<td bgcolor="rgb(204,209,209)">Row2 Col2</td>`

Comment: `var tableHTMLData = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20').replace('#', '%23')`

Comment: Or use `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: Thank you so much @blurfus  - your answers helped me use a different format for bgcolor and it worked! I do not see any option to upvote your comments (or accept your answers) - how do I do that? (I am new to this site and it said I should see an upward triangle next to comments, but I dont)

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams for all the options- your first answer is similar to what I did , to avoid the  # character. (again - how do I upvote/accept these solutions?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess that because `#` has a special meaning in an URL so that when you add it as part of the `download.href` it truncates the content until that point.

You are likely going to need to add a class to assign colour to the `bgcolor` via CSS.

So in your HTML, instead of `<td bgcolor="#CCD1D1">Row2 Col2</td>`

you can have something like:

`<td class="mygray">Row2 Col2</td>`

and then your CSS will have something like

```css
.mygray{
   background-color: #CCD1D1;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
.mygray {
  background-color: #CCD1D1;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygray">Row2 Col2</div>
<hr/>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="mygray">Row2 Col2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```